# How does the Elementary School Principal get away with so much?

Tags: gakuen-alice

In Gakuen Alice, the Elementary School Principal is involved with a lot of things that seem to be illegal, including

> the death of Mikan's father.

Is it ever said in the manga how he can get away with that? Why doesn't anyone (including the government) stop him or at least try to prosecute him?

Answer (score 2):

Everything I found is this:

> He is known to cause countless chaos to the academy without leaving enough proof for his actions, which explains why he has never been punished.

Source: http://gakuenalice.wikia.com/wiki/Kuonji